# MySQL column encoding after converting to PHPBB3 from VBulletin 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encoding, phpbb3

The following screen shot is going to be good introduction for the issue:

[image]

It is from phpmyadmin for the table topics of phpbb3. It shows that at the same table there are two columns one renders text in wrong encoding `topic_title` and other `topic_first_poster_name` renders the text correct.

In the [convert script](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=1722325) I set the `$encoding` to be `windows-1256` as advised because my later VB forum was using `windows-1256`.

The screen shotted table has `utf8_bin` collation and topic_title collation is `utf8_unicode_ci` while `topic_first_poster_name` is `utf8_bin`.

**What I need is to convert the text of topic_title to be rendered correctly because it make phpbb3 to render it wrong.**

I tried the hint in [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/) about fixing column encoding but I miss able to determine what encoding that I have to use:

```
UPDATE table SET column=CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(column USING binary) USING utf8) USING cp1251) WHERE id=123;
```

I have made the following using cp1256 but I did not get any result:

```
UPDATE t_topics SET topic_title=CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(topic_title USING binary) USING utf8) USING cp1256) WHERE topic_id=2
```

### Update:

When I alter the chaset i.e makin cp1256 first then utf8, the field text becomes like the following and it also wrong:
[image]

### Update 2:

Using the following in the application `viewtopic.php` solve the problem in the browser's window:

```
'TOPIC_TITLE'   =>  iconv( "UTF-8","Windows-1256//TRANSLIT", utf8_encode($topic_data['topic_title']))
```

However, what would this indicate in-order to solve this issue from the database field itself?

Comment: if you did an `alter .... charset windows-1256`, then mysql already converted the field for you as part of the alter statement. Doing an update as you are is trashing the data by taking what is already 1256, treating it as utf8, and REconverting it to 1256.

Comment: @MarcB I did not alter anything, I just created a db and I let the converter script to do everything as described above

Comment: @MarcB Could you please get a look at the updates?!